# If I store session in localStorage rather than cookies, would my web site be more secure?

Tags: http, session, authentication, cookies

As far as I know, most of websites with authentication work this way:

1. The user send username-password pair with a POST form.
2. The server identify the user and store session key in his cookie with the header of HTTP response.
3. When user clicks any link on the web page, the browser sends a GET request, along with the session key we just set.
4. The server identify the user by the session key in cookie.

And it causes some problems, like [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). I know none of them is unsolvable, but consider this approach:

1. The user send username-password pair with a POST via Ajax.
2. The server response a session key in the body of HTTP response.
3. The client javascript stores the session key in localStorage/DOM.
4. When user clicks any link on the web page, the javascript prevents browser's default behavior, and sends a GET request via Ajax, with the session key we just set.(e.g. `http://www.myapp.com/articles?session_key=af18db9c10a916ec12`)
5. The server identify the user by the GET parameter.

Does this approach work better in terms of security? What are its drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

It's a neat idea. Two quick things jump to mind (though I'm sure there's more to say):

1. In the end, you're still sending a session key from the browser to the server, you're just using the `GET ...` header line instead of the `Cookie: ...` line. A hacker can still break this by spoofing the entire request. However, specifically regarding XSRF attacks in which a hacker tricks the user into unintentionally submitting a form on a trusted site, your scheme probably reduces the risk by supplying the session key only for links within the running application (as opposed to on every page load as with cookies). Cool!
2. Some browsers (especially in the corporate world) completely disable javascript for security reasons. It's a small percentage of the overall web-using population, but you'll have to take your audience into consideration. In general, it's a risk to change the default browser behavior.

**Addendum:**

One "standard" way to foil XSRF attacks, is to randomly generate a token while serving any page that contains a form. The token is stored in the session on the server, and in a hidden field in the form that is being served. When the form is submitted, you check that it contains a token matching the one in the server's session. This is essentially the same as your solution (it guarantees that the form is submitted from a page served from your application), but does not necessitate changing the default browser behavior.